# Strange flex behaviour

Tags: flex-lexer, lexical-analysis

I have a scanner for a *[dice notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dice_notation)* with the following scanner

```
%option debug
%option noyywrap
%option yylineno

%{    
#include <limits.h>
#include "parser.h"
%} 

%%

[0-9]+      {
    errno = 0;
#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("Scanner: NUMBER %s (%i)\n", yytext, yyleng);
#endif
    long number =  strtol( yytext, NULL, 10);
    if ( errno != 0 && errno != ERANGE && number == 0 ) {
        printf("Error: incorrect number %s\n", yytext);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    // we only accept integers
    if ( number > INT_MAX ) {
        printf("Error: %s is too large\n", yytext );
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    yylval.int_type = (int)number;
    return NUMBER;
}

\+          { return PLUS;    }

\-          { return MINUS;   }

["*"x]      { return TIMES;   }

\/          { return DIV;     }

d|D         {
#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("Scanner: DICE\n");
#endif
    return DICE;
}

f|F         { return FUDGE;   }

h|H         { return HIGH;    }

l|L         { return LOW;     }

"("         { return LPAREN;  }

")"         { return RPAREN;  }

"{"         {
#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("Scanner: LCURLY\n");
#endif
    return LCURLY;
}

"}"         {
#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("Scanner: RCURLY\n");
#endif
    return RCURLY;
}

">"         { return GT; }
">="        { return GE; }
"<"         { return LT; }
"<="        { return LE; }
"!="        { return NE; }
"<>"        { return NE; }
"%"         { return PERCENT; }

,           {
#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("Scanner: COMMA\n");
#endif
    return COMMA;
}

[[:blank:]] {
    /* ignore spaces */
#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("Scanner: BLANK\n");
#endif
}

.           { printf("Error: unknown symbol '%s'\n", yytext); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }

%%
```

When I parse something like `4{3d6, 1d5}` everything works fine. But with `4{3d6,1d5}` the scanner has a strange behaviour and misses the first curly bracket.

The debugging output is

```
--accepting rule at line 20 ("43")
Scanner: NUMBER 43 (2)
--accepting rule at line 47 ("d")
Scanner: DICE
--accepting rule at line 20 ("641")
Scanner: NUMBER 641 (3)
--accepting rule at line 47 ("d")
Scanner: DICE
```

The scanner is matching `4{3` as `43` although the `{` is not included in `[0-9]+`.

As the different behaviour is triggered by a blank much later in the expression I suspect that I have missed something in the space handling but I do not see why it should mess with the matching of an integer at the beginning of the expression.

Any hint?

Comment: Are you doing something odd with `yytext` in the calling code?

Comment: @EJP I am not modifying it anywhere. The problem just appears when no spaces are present in the expression

Comment: Note also the error with `641`. My next question would be whether you're sure the input really looks the way you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a Unix shell is getting its hands on your input `4{3d6,1d5}` would be expanded to `43d6 41d5`. Your lexer completely ignores blanks, so that then becomes `43d641d5`, which (modulo some truncation on your part?) is what you're reporting.

I duplicated your code, and when I run something like:

```
echo 4{3d6,1d5} | ./lex
```

I get your problem. If I run:

```
echo '4{3d6,1d5}' | ./lex
```

then everything is fine. It's also fine if I type `4{3d6,1d5}` into a file, and then run the lexer on the file.

Comment: Agreed — I think this is the correct diagnosis (I can reproduce the behaviour too).

Comment: Oh my ... I feel so stupid. I was trying to debug the code without thinking about the shell expansion. ... Thanks!